# Can't find a value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, image

I'm looking for an image in a column, I know it's there. But when I select, I can't find it. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture),
    COUNT(*) AS Count    -- convert(nvarchar,(MAX(employeeid)))
FROM  
    TABLENAME
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture)
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    Count
```

I get a result and a count 4. When I query the table using

```
Select CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture),employeeid from TABLENAME where CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture) = 'value from result 1'
```

and the value in a select statement, I get nothing.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that, mssql

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The result i want is pretty simple, four rows with the same image value and different employee id's

Comment: Where is `employee id` in your query?

Comment: the employee id i only need when i query the table using the picture column. This is the situation, i know in this table there are duplicate photos. After using my first query, i know there are four images with the same value. Now i use that picture value in a select statement to find the four employee id's , no result. I dont know why.

Comment: `having count(distinct employee_id) > 1`?

Comment: no thats not going to work because the employee id is unique and only the photo is the same. So the same photo got uploaded for diffrent people which is incorrect. Its a table with 3000 people so i cant come up with another way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you want to identify rows where the same image is used more than once then you can do:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT employeeid,
           Picture,
           COUNT(employeeid) OVER (PARTITION BY Picture) AS Entries
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Entries > 1;
```

Also, I suspect your query didn't work because you had:

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture) = 'value from result 1'
```

You're *implying* that you put the value of the previous `varbinary` in literal string quotes. The values `0x01` and `'0x01'` are **not** the same (`SELECT CASE WHEN 0x01 = '0x01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` returns `0`). `'0x01'` is a **string representation** of a `varbinary`, however, if you cast that value to a `varbinary` you get `0x30783031` (`SELECT CASE WHEN 0x30783031 = '0x01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` returns 1).

Answer (score 0):

You get nothing because you are performing a STRING search on BINARY data.

```
where CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture) = 'value from result 1'
```

The left part is Binary, the right part is a string (CHAR)

You should convert again your VARBINARY to VARCHAR to perform the string search :

```
Select CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture),
       employeeid 
from TABLENAME 
where CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Picture),1) = 'value from result 1'
```

The `,1` is the "style" that tells SQL server to return the string in binary notation, ie with `0x` appended at the begining, which is how your "binary strings" are supposed to be returned by your first query. See **Binary styles** on [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)